# how to add "android.library=true" with the "android update" command

Tags: android, project, build-automation, android-build

I want to build an Android project from command-line and want to add the `android.library=true` flag to the project.properties. I also want to do it with he the `android` command from the sdk and NOT add it manually to the file, because file- and property-names could change.

the command `android update lib-project -p PATH` does not add this flag anymore.

the command `android create lib-project ...` does "add" this flag, but overrides some files like string resources

So my question is: it is possible with the `android` tool to make a project.properties that has this android.library flag set to true, and doesn't do much more?

What is the difference between `android update project` and `android update lib-project` beside I cannot use some flags in lib-project?

Answer (score 1):

From http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingLibraryProject

With android update lib-project you can only update the build target and the path.
Check your command
This is the syntax to update the lib-project

android update lib-project \
--target  \
--path path/to/your/project

you are trying to update with just -p

Answering your second question the command name itself tells the answer that "android update project" is used to update the projects which is not a library project but a normal project. whereas "android update lib-project" is used to update the library projects.

Comment: Who down voted for this if you are sure this solution wont work provide a valid comment.

Comment: i didn't downvote you but you also dind't gave a proper answer to the question. I use `--target` inside the command but left it out because it doesn't change anything. The question was how to add `android.library=true` to the project-properties.

Comment: To add android.library=true to project.properties as per my knowledge is only possible with "android create lib-project" which you had already specified it does this right, hence I answered your second question and explained about the update and create with syntax.

Comment: ok, but in eclipse->rightClickOnProject->Properties->Android->check "isLibrary" does exactly this. `android create lib-project ...` isn't usable, because on an already created project it breaks too much

Comment: yes checking on isLibrary does the same, It doesn't makes sense using android create lib-project on already created project, but you can use android update lib-project instead to update the path.